# ASP.NET MVC WebApi Integration testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, integration-testing

I am trying to write integration tests for my ASP.NET MVC WebApi application. I am using `MvcIntegrationTestFramework` described [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/06/11/integration-testing-your-aspnet-mvc-application/).

I have test class for my controller as below:

```
public class UsersControllerTests
{
    private AppHost appHost;

    public UsersControllerTests()
    {
        appHost = AppHost.Simulate("MyApplication");
    }

    [Test]
    public void given_valid_user_name_should_exist()
    {
        appHost.Start(browsingSession =>
        {
            var userName = "name";
            var response = browsingSession.Get($"users/{userName}");

            var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserDto>(response.ResponseText);
            user.UserName.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(userName);

            Assert.IsTrue(response.IsSuccess);
        });
    }
}
```

My issue is that when I run the test, `response.ResponseText` returns empty string.

My Controller action:

```
[Route("users/{name}")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string name)
{
    var user = await _userService.GetByNameAsync(name);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Json(user);
}
```

I will add that I am using `Unity Container` in my application.
Additional as described in blog post I provided, it says that I have to copy testing DLLs (`FluentAssertions, NUnit.Framework`) to the main application bin folder. Is there any work around for this?

One last question. I read an [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing)

about integration testing for .NET Core and I wonder if I could use it in my application?

Comment: I believe that your Web Api is running before you run Integration test. Otherwise it will return empty. So you need to run Api project first. Then you need to pass the whole url in test cases.

Comment: @BasantaMatia Unfortunately I don't know what you mean. Can you please clarify? I can explain if something is not clear.

Comment: Are you testing with real data, i mean frm database or using Mock ?

Comment: @BasantaMatia I have class called InMemorrUser repository where I have initialized list of fake users.